# ¿2 Collection View en el mismo ViewController?

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview

Adjunto imagen de lo que quiero hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el siguiente codigo, tengo un codigo de una collection donde al clicar una imagen paso con un segue a otro VC con la misma imagen más grande.
¿Como podría hacer para cambiar el segue por poner la imagen grande en el mismo VC?

Este es mi actual código:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let tvSeries = ["Perdidos", "Friends", "Breaking Bad", "Dexter"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tvSeries.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let identifier = "Item"

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! SeriesCollectionViewCell

        cell.itemLabel.text = tvSeries[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemImage.image = UIImage.init(imageLiteralResourceName: tvSeries[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let item = sender as? UICollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: item!)
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        detailVC.detailName = tvSeries[(indexPath?.row)!]
    }


}
```

Comment: ¡Muy bien planteado, ahora sí! En castellano y mostrando el código

Answer (score 0):

Para tener 2 collectionViews en el mismo controlador no tienes que hacer ningún segue. Lo que tienes que tener son 2 collectionViews (imaginemos collectionViewArriba y collectionViewAbajo) e implementar el método didSelectItemAtIndexPath, una vez pulsada una celda en collectionViewAbajo puedes acceder al elemento clicado de la misma forma que tienes, usando tvSeries[indexPath.row]

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if collectionview == collectionViewAbajo {
        let item = tvSeries[indexPath.row]

        //imagino que de aqui podras sacar la imagen y se la puedes poner a la imagen que deberias tener encima del collcetionView
        self.imagen.image = item.imagen
    }
}
```

No me queda muy claro lo de los 2 collectionView. Si lo que quieres es que cuando pulses una imagen de abajo te aparezca en otro collectionView de arriba, eso es otra cosa, debería tener las imágenes en el collectionView de arriba ya cargadas, o cuando se pulse en el de abajo que aparezca en el de arriba o un método para saber que cuando pulse en el de abajo que se debe reflejar en el de arriba. Podrías ser mas especifico, pero imaginando que tienes otro array como modelo de datos solo con las imágenes del collectionViewAbajo podrías hacer esto otro:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
    if collectionView == collectionViewAbajo {
        collectionViewArriba.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Siendo collectionViewArriba la collectionView grande, en la que el modelo de datos esta relacionado con tvSeries, de forma que el elemento 1 esta reverenciado por el elemento 1 de ese otro modelo de datos.

Siento no poderte ayudar mas, pero no me ha quedado claro como quieres mostrar las imagines de arriba o como lo tienes implementado.

Answer (score 0):

no parece mal como lo estas planteando... creo que aun falta registrar la clase de las celdas y añadirlas al id de las celdas en tu caso es "item"
... ya tienes creadas los ítems en las secciones... y también las celdas..
por cierto no es necesario un segue...

lo primero es
crear una clase: // si ya la tienes no es necesario obviamente!

class CeldaTvSeries: UICollectionViewCell  {
     override init(frame:CGRect)
          super.init(frame: frame)

```
// en este punto es donde se colocan los objetos que vas creando es como el viewDidLoad()
```

}.    (aqui el compilador necesita un required init, simplemente le das en el botón automático de fix y Xcode lo coloca por ti...

tus colecciones donde tienes tus tv series simplemente las implementas en esta clase...

y para registrar las celdas...

en el viewDidLoad()...  collectionView.register("clase creada", forcellWithReusIdentifier: "id de tus celdas"

también otra cosa.. se necesita darle tamaño a esas celdas.. agrega en la clase UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout para que puedas utilizar la función

sizeForItemAt esta devuelve un CGRect.. pones:

return CGRect(width: view.frame.widht, height: 140"o el tamaño que quieras")

y con eso ya tienes que poder ver tu collectionView...

esta manera es sin usar el storyboard, pero te puede servir...y
con eso ya tiene que aparecer en tu ViewController la colección, no olvides darle las propiedades que necesitas como el scroll y demás saludos ojalá te sirva de ayuda